# Magnific Popup Layout / Move title to right side of image?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have a simple enough task i'm trying to achieve here. But i'm getting a little lost with jquery's magnific popup.

[VIEW IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er3xM.jpg)

I have passed into the popup the text/buttons by inserting the code into the images title, so it's displayed in the 'mfp-title' class section. My question is how do i go about moving it from underneath, to the right side, so that its on a white background the same height as the image, and having the entire thing centred once there, if it isn't already.

The image iv'e added shows (in red) what im trying to move / where to.

It's currently being used as follow's:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.thumbnails').magnificPopup({
    type:'image',
    delegate: 'a',
    gallery: {
        enabled:true
    },  
    image: {
    markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
             '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +

             '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +  
             '<figure>'+'<figcaption>'+
               '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
                 '<div style="background: #fff; text-align: center"  class="mfp-title"></div>' +

               '</div>'+
             '</figcaption>'+
             '</figure>' +
           '</div>'
    }
});
```

});

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!